# React Mobx component not update after store change

Tags: reactjs, meteor, mobx, mobx-react

I would like create global Notification component in my React App. I've add **mobx-react** for create a Notification store :

```
class NotificationStore {
  @observable message = '';
  @observable isActive = false;
}

const store = new NotificationStore;

export default store;
```

And my Component, added in my Layout :

```
@observer
class NotificationBox extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <h1>{this.props.store.message}</h1>
    );
  }
}

export { NotificationBox };
```

My Layout :

```
<NotificationBox store={store} />
```

And my code for update my store (send form, for example) :

```
<a onClick={this.update}>Update my store</a>

update() {
  store.message = 'My new message !';
  store.isActive = true;
}
```

This example update my store, but my Notification component view is not update. I don't know why :(

Anyone have idea ?

Thank you community !

Comment: Please include all relevant code or create an isolated example. It [**works for me**](http://jsbin.com/qidivirifo/edit?js,console,output). Try to write `store.message = 'foobar';` in the console to see the component re-render.

Comment: Hi @Thollle :) I'm on MeteorJS, i can't post JSBin example :(. In Meteor, when i update my store with store.message = 'test', my console.log() is good, but my view don't update :/